# Apache rewrite including query string manipulation

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Need to rewrite the following:

/bob/dave/XXX/?id=passport

to

/lucy/bob/dave/?path=XXX&id=passport

XXX being whatever

Not had a chance test yet but will post as soon as I have.

Any pointers would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Update: This is what I have so far:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} "^bert.com$" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/bob/dave/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\?id=([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$" [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://lucy/bob/dave/?path=$1&id=$2 [L,R=301]`

I suspect I will have to use a QSA for part of this.

Answer (score 0):

Got there in the end - this seems to work:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} "^bert.com$" [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^id=([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$" [NC]
RewriteRule ^/bob/dave/([A-Za-z0-9-]+) https://lucy/bob/dave/?urlPath=$1&icid=%1 [L,R=301]`